# Codeigniter form validation. Alpha and spaces

Tags: codeigniter

When using Codeigniter form validation, does alpha allow spaces? Ex. "Bob Smith"

Comment: Did you test it?  According to [the docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference), it's just "alphabetical characters", so no spaces.

Comment: yups, it doesn't allow space, but you can create a callback function to check it. see this site for detail, [http://nanamo3lyana.blogspot.com/2012/06/simple-function-to-validate-alpha.html](http://nanamo3lyana.blogspot.com/2012/06/simple-function-to-validate-alpha.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not allow spaces.

Someone wrote a library extension that allows that though: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/158696/#794699

Answer (score 17):

Here is a code that should solve your problem:

```
function alpha_dash_space($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z_ ])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

In the rules, you can call it like follows:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', trim|xss_clean|callback_alpha_dash_space');
```

Edit

Removed one extra _ from callback_alpha_dash_space

Comment: Just a little side note: CI 2.1.4 only takes one underscore when setting the validation function as a callback (i.e. 'callback_alpha_dash_space').

Comment: I used it and it allowed numbers as well...should have limited itself to alpha only

Comment: if I wanted to not allow dash, then would the regular expression be `/^([a-z_ ])+$/i` ?

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm late to answer this. But for those who are still looking for an answer on how to just allow letters and white spaces, you can follow this:

**In form validation**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'Fullname', 'min_length[7]|trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_dash_space');
```

**Then add a callback function for alpha_dash_space**

```
function alpha_dash_space($fullname){
    if (! preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $fullname)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_dash_space', 'The %s field may only contain alpha characters & White spaces');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

- `^` and `$` Tells that it is the beginning and the end of the string
- `a-z` are lowercase letters, `A-Z` are uppercase letters
- `\s` is whitespace and `+` means 1 or more times.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 3):

One line solution:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('field', 'Field', 'regex_match[/^([a-z ])+$/i]');
```

Alpha characters and space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$field = trim($_POST['field']);
$_POST['field'] = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['field']);
```

and check it as alpha in the rule, then you can use $field after successful validation.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field', 'FIELD', 'alpha');
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is

by using alpha_numeric_spaces in your form validation
This allow user to input alphabet, numeric, and whitespace

Example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules
        ('username', 
        'Username', 
        'required|alpha_numeric_spaces|trim|is_unique[user.username]',
        [
            
            'required' => 'Error msg',
            'alpha_numeric_spaces'=>'Error msg for alpha_numeric_spaces',
            'is_unique' => 'Error msg'
        ]  
        );
```