# codeigniter alpha_numeric form validation not accepting space

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, numeric

i want to set form validation so that user cannot add special characters like $, @, &, etc... only alpha numeric characters are allow

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_name', 'Category Name', 'trim|xss_clean|required|is_unique[cht_category.cat_name]|min_length[5]|max_length[75]|alpha_numeric');
```

when i add category name with space then i get following error
"The Category Name field may only contain alpha-numeric characters."
when i add category name without space or single word then its working fine

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
alpha_numeric_spaces
```

Ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, `alpha_numeric` won't allow spaces to pass. Instead of using `alpha_numeric`, you can write your own function and pass it there ([Codeigniter form validation. Alpha and spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164548/codeigniter-form-validation-alpha-and-spaces)):

```
function alpha_dash_space($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z_ ])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

and then

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_name', 'Category Name', 'trim|xss_clean|required|is_unique[cht_category.cat_name]|min_length[5]|max_length[75]|callback__alpha_dash_space');
```

Comment: i have tried this but it will add special charaters like business types $ now i dont want to add these kinds of characters