# How to remove everything but allow letter, number and underscore?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to remove everything but allow letter, number and underscore only in my validation for the username? I tried this code but it allows space:

```
function customUsername($username) 
{
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z.,\-]+$/i',$username))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('customUsername', 'The username field');
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter alpha\_numeric form validation not accepting space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561943/codeigniter-alpha-numeric-form-validation-not-accepting-space)

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164548/codeigniter-form-validation-alpha-and-spaces

Comment: Try my answer hope it will work for you

Comment: Thanks for the link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561943/codeigniter-alpha-numeric-form-validation-not-accepting-space) @GaneshAher It helps me that I should use alpha_dash instead of callback.

Comment: Always welcome...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex

```
function customUsername($username) 
{
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/i',$username))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('customUsername', 'The username field');
    }
}
```

Comment: The statement inside IF statement will be executed if spaces is present in the $username. So what is your use case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASCII code of every letter, number and underscore.

follow this link for ASCII code http://ascii.cl/ .

jQuery is like this.

```
$('#keyId').keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;            
    return (
        key == 8 || 
        (key >= 23 && key <= 105)
     );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So Simple It allow only `Alphanumeric` and `Underscore` only

```
<?php

    $str='fdfdf5_';

    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/',$str))
    {
       echo "success";   
    }
    else
    {
      echo "failed";   
    }

    ?>
```